# What is the mtxrun error about 'context.lua' and how to fix it?

Tags: context, pandoc

Trying my first steps in the Tex world.
I'm trying to achieve the result for : [Pandoc Resume](https://github.com/mszep/pandoc_resume),  which creates an intermediary `tex` file before a convertion to `pdf` using `mtxrun`.

Unfortunately, I cannot manage to convert the `tex` file into a `pdf` file.

```
mtxrun | unknown script 'context.lua' or 'mtx-context.lua'
```

It *seems* to be a fairly old error, dating back to 2011, and the internet resources say to do:

```
luatools --generate
```

But despite this operation, I still have the same error.

```
mtxrun | unknown script 'context.lua' or 'mtx-context.lua'
```

I cannot see clearly what's going wrong. So it is not easy to find the solution.
Any insight?

I am using the linux distribution Nixos v18.03
mtxrun is version 1.32 from package:     texlive.combined.scheme-context

Comment: Welcome! What operating system are you using, and what TeX distribution (i.e., how did you install TeX and ConTeXt)? The repo you linked to has [instructions](https://github.com/mszep/pandoc_resume#requirements) for Debian / Ubuntu, Fedora, Arch, and OSX; did you use one of these? Also, at the very [end](https://github.com/mszep/pandoc_resume#context-executable-cannot-be-found), it suggests `mtxrun --generate`; did you try this?

Comment: I have edited the question: I use Nixos and the texlive.combined.scheme-context ackage. I did not read the very end... And after running this command it solves the problem.

Comment: That's great! Please post it as an answer (yes it's ok to answer your own question) and mark it as accepted, so that someone else who has the same problem can find the solution here (instead of whatever you found on the internet).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I'm gonna do this. Just thinking about not paraphrasing too much. Also I want to check how I can modify the nixos derivation/package file so as to complete this operation automatically.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR and StephaneRolland Please write an answer or close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: @HenriMenke done.

Answer (score 5):

As suggested at the end of [this page](https://github.com/mszep/pandoc_resume#requirements), running the command:

```
mtxrun --generate
```

solves the problem. Further calls to `texlive` now execute successfully.

**I am searchin for a way to automatically do this** in the `nixos` derivation. I'll edit with the result here when I'm done.

Comment: That does nothing for me. Thanks for sharing though.

Comment: This worked for me but I have no idea why